# Getting a weird 'local variable referenced before assignment' error

Tags: python-3.x

Here's the code - it's a class method.

```
    def update(self,xxx):
        print("update=" + str(xxx))
        
        str = "{:.2f}".format(xxx)
```

getting error on the print statement.

`NameError: local variable referenced before assignment`

I've changed xxx name to other random names - same error.

If I comment out the format statement - then no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't with the `xxx` parameter, but with the local `str` variable.

The intent of the code isn't entirely clear to me, but if you rename the `str` variable to something else (`foo`, for example), it should work:

```
def update(self, xxx):
    print("update=" + str(xxx))

    foo = "{:.2f}".format(xxx)
```

By the way, I would caution against using `str` (and the names of other built-ins like `input` etc.) as variable names. It makes the code less clear. It also shadows built-ins, causing strange behavior when you try to use said built-ins.

Comment: I was trying to call the builtin function `str` to convert float to string. not recommended?

Comment: No, that's fine, and `"{:.2f}".format(xxx)` is a good way to do that.

Comment: ok - still like to know why i'm getting the error message.

Comment: You were using the `str` variable before defining it.

Comment: My apologies - I completely missed the fact that I created a `str` variable name. duh!

Comment: No worries! Those "oops" bugs can be the most frustrating to debug.

Answer (score 0):

**Change str to string or another variable name**

Your second variable "str" cannot be this is because the prebuilt function "str()" exists in python. It might confuse your code on what's happening and assume that you are trying to reassign str from a built-in function into something else.